# If $O_a=\{f \in L^\infty(\Omega):\|f-u_a\|_\infty<\frac{1}{2}\}$ then $O_a \cap O_b=\emptyset$ if $a \neq b$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, separable-spaces

This is part of the proof of Remark 9 ($L^\infty(\Omega)$ is not separable) in the French version of Brézis book.

Let $\Omega$ be a open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For each $a \in \Omega$ fix $r_a< \hbox{dist}(a,\complement \Omega)$. Define $u_a=1_{B(a,r_a)}$ and

$$O_a=\{f \in L^\infty(\Omega):\|f-u_a\|_\infty<\frac{1}{2}\}.$$

It is easy to show that $O_a$ is open and non-empty and $\{O_a\}$ is non-countable.

**My question:** How to prove that $O_a \cap O_b=\emptyset$ if $a \neq b$?

Suppose that for $a \neq b$ we have $O_a \cap O_b \neq \emptyset$, so that there exists $f \in O_a \cap O_b$.
Following the English version, I was trying to prove that $\|u_a-u_b\|_\infty=1$, so that we will have $1=\|u_a-u_b\|\leq\|u_a-f\|_\infty+\|u_b-f\|_\infty < \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$, which is a absurd.

So my question boils down to how to show that

$$\|u_a-u_b\|_\infty=1.$$

Comment: It should be clear that $||u_a-u_b||_\infty \le 1$ because at any point the difference is either $0$ or $1$. In the same way we already see that $||u_a-u_b||_\infty =0$ is not possible if $a \ne b$ because $B(b,r_b) \ne B(a,r_a)$ (if the balls were the same they would have to have the same radius and therefore also the same mid-point). That means there is a $c \in \Omega$ for which $|u_a(c)-u_b(c)|=1$ because it is only in one of the two balls. That leads to $||u_a-u_b||_\infty =1$.

Comment: @Lukas Wouldn't it be necessary to find a set $A$ with $|A|>0$ and $|u_a(x)-u_b(x)|=1$ in $A$? If we have this, then $\|u_a-u_b\|_\infty<1$ can not occur, because we would have $1 \leq \|u_a-u_b\|_\infty<1$ which is a absurd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given two open balls $B(a,r)$ and $B = B(b,s)$ such that if $a \ne b$.  Without loss of generality, $s \ge r$.

If $|b-a| \ge r + s$, then the two balls are disjoint, and so $u_a$ and $u_b$ disagree on a non-empty open set.

Otherwise, we have $s > \tfrac12|b-a|$.

Let $u = (b-a)/|b-a|$.  Let $c = b + (s-\tfrac12|b-a|) u$.  Then $B(c,\tfrac12|b-a|) \subset B(b,s) \setminus B(a,r)$.

Proof:  Note first that $|b-c| = s - \tfrac12|b-a|$ and $|a-c| = s + \tfrac12|b-a|$.

Suppose $x \in B(c,\tfrac12|b-a|)$, that is $|x-c| < \tfrac12 |b-a|$.  Then $|x-b| \le |x-c| + |b-c| < \tfrac12|b-a| + s-\tfrac12|b-a| = s$, so $x \in B(b,s)$.  Also $|x-a| \ge |c-a| - |x-c| > s+\tfrac12|b-a| - \tfrac12|b-a| = s \ge r$.  So $x \notin B(a,r)$.

So $u_a$ and $u_b$ disagree on $B(c,\tfrac12|b-a|)$ which is a non-empty open set.